# GO: {GOOS} and {GOARCH} not recognised in environment

Tags: command-line, go

I want to change my diretory to `go/pkg/darwin_amd64` but `$ cd $GOPATH/pkg/${GOOS}_${GOARCH}` doesn't find the folder though directory exists.

`$ echo $GOPATH/pkg/${GOOS}_${GOARCH}` gives `/go/pkg/_` instead of `/go/pkg/darwin_amd64`.

`$ go env` prints:

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/sahilkapoor/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
CC="clang"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fno-common"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

We can see that `GOOS` and `GOARCH` are defined here. I am using terminal on Mac OSX 10.10.3. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$GOOS` and `$GOARCH` will only be defined in your shell if you have exported them (which, unless you are doing cross compilation, is unlikely).

When you run `go env`, default values are shown when they have not been overwritten by your environment. You should change your command to the following to get the desired results:

```
cd $(go env GOPATH)/pkg/$(go env GOOS)_$(go env GOARCH)
```

Comment: Thanks but is there a way to export these values into my default environment?

Comment: @SahilKapoor: In your .bashrc (or similar), you could add the line: `. <(go env)`